# how to force hibernate to load data from database?

Tags: hibernate, native

Problem with hibernate:

I update a column "count" in a table "data" with a native query in my source code. Later I want to load all rows from table "data" but the value of column "count" has not changed.

Rows from table "data" are loaded with:

...
.createQuery("from data")
.setCacheable(false)
.list();

Any idea what's wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

`setCacheable(false)` isn't useful (it's the default). The cache it refers to is the second-level cache. You probably have loaded some entities in the session (i.e. the first-level cache) before executing your update query. In this case, the select query will perform against the database, but will return the already-loaded entities from the session. You thus need to [evict](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) these entities from the session before executing the select query, or to completely [clear](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear%28%29) the session.

If the entities are cached in the second-level cache, then you also have to evict them from the second-level cache. See [getCache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCache%28%29).